# Foreach for nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 0
            [Nickname] => nickname1
            [Score] => 291
            [Ping] => 204
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 1
            [Nickname] => nickname2
            [Score] => 4619
            [Ping] => 309
        )
)
```

and I used this code:

```
    <?php

    $API_GET = file_get_contents("player_list.php"); 
    $API_GET = json_decode($API_GET); 
    $API = array(); 
 foreach($API_GET as $ID => $Info)
 {
    $Player[$ID] = $Info;
    foreach($Info as $key => $value)
   { 
        $API[$key] = $value; 
        echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
  }

 ?>
```

And I get the warning "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" and I'm not sure what's causing this because I'm really new to PHP.

~Stanley

Comment: What is $Info in second for each?

Comment: Your `foreach` loops are not nested: the closing `}` after `$Info;` terminates the first loop.

Comment: try changing `{ $Player[ID] = $Info;}` to `{ $Player[ID] = $Info;`, and `{ $API[$key] = $value; }` to `{ $API[$key] = $value; } }`

Comment: are you sure  $API_GET = json_decode($API_GET); is actually returning a value and isn't null

Answer (score 1):

You have closed the brackets early. Check it out:

```
 $API_GET = file_get_contents("player_list.php"); 
 $API_GET = json_decode($API_GET);
 $API = array(); 
 foreach($API_GET as $ID => $Info)
 {
    $Player[$ID] = $Info;
    foreach($Info as $key => $value)
   { 
        $API[$key] = $value; 
        echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same warning, not sure why. Anyways here's the whole code:                                                                                                                                                `<?php

    $API_GET = file_get_contents("player_list.php"); 
 $API_GET = json_decode($API_GET); 
    $API = array(); 
 foreach($API_GET as $ID => $Info)
 {
    $Player[$ID] = $Info;
    foreach($Info as $key => $value)
   { 
        $API[$key] = $value; 
        echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
  }
    



 
 ?>`   Sorry for the mess :)

Comment: Did you try var_dump($API_GET) to check whether you receiving the data properly from the API?

Comment: You have extra slashes around the API file name. Check my edited answer.

Comment: It was returning a null value and it seems to be the problem. I'll let you know when I fix it :) Thanks for your quick response :P